# How to access TextMate grammar parsing results from Language Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension with syntax highlighting support – I described language grammar via `.tmLanguage.json` file. Now I want to improve this extension with [DocumentSymbolProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbolProvider) – and it appears that now I need to implement all the grammar parsing, including tokenization, from scratch. Is there any option to access grammar parsing results via VS Code API?

Answer (score 1):

Found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate, that is the tool that VS Code uses [internally](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/82e645cf851a6f274c7930a064671381cee06a29/src/vs/workbench/services/textMate/common/TMGrammarFactory.ts#L7)